# Intermittent Validation Problems using ServiceSttack

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack to build an API and at the same time, I'm using the plugin that allows Razor views to return html to browsers.

I have validation set up and configured correctly. I know this because I get the validation messages on the corresponding Razor view and the messages are accurate. However, if I modify the Razor view **at all** (and by "at all" I mean something as simple as adding a line break and then immediately deleting it), I get a 500 error accompanied by a blank page.

Other times, while in the process of simply refreshing the page to review styling of the Razor view, the validation simply returns a blank page with the same non-useful 500 error. And of course, if I remove the validation, the Razor view renders just fine 100% of the time.

What must I do to have validation working at all times? My code is straight forward and matches everything that I've been able to read in the Docs. Namely, both the response and the requests are in the same namespace and the validator is coded to the request.

**Here is the request DTO**

```
namespace MyServer.DTO
{
    [Validator(typeof(SignUpValidator))]
    [Route("SignUp")]
    public class SignUp : IReturn<SignUpResponse>
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Here is the corresponding validator**

```
namespace MyServer.DTO
{
    public class SignUpValidator : AbstractValidator<SignUp>
    {
        public SignUpValidator()
        {
            RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () =>
                {
                    RuleFor(e => e.UserName).NotEmpty();
                    RuleFor(e => e.Email).NotEmpty();
                    RuleFor(e => e.EmailConfirm).NotEmpty();
                    RuleFor(e => e.Password).NotEmpty();
                    RuleFor(e => e.PasswordConfirm).NotEmpty();
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the response**

```
namespace MyServer.DTO
{
    public class SignUpResponse
    {
        bool DidSucceed { get; set; }
        int NewUserId { get; set; }
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**And lastly, here is the code that configures the validation plugin**

```
        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
        Container.RegisterValidators(typeof(SignUpService).Assembly);
```

As you can see, everything is pretty vanilla and by the book, but this setup is very fragile for some reason. Any modification to the corresponding Razor view and I get the aforementioned errors. Then I have to recompile repeatedly until it works again.

I should also mention that, if I use the REST Console (google chrome extension thingy) to test this, I get the following results when posting to the **exact same** URI:

- Content-Type set to : *application/json* - Everything works as intended. 400 Response with the errors listed in the response body.
- Content-Type set to : *application/html* - Consistently breaks. 500 Response with no data in the response body.

There must be something that I'm missing.

Thanks so much for your time and I would appreciate any help.

Thanks again.

Comment: Try setting `DebugMode = true` and see if it helps by giving some error information. Have you overridden any of the default error handlers? eg: `CustomErrorHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.NotFound] = new RazorHandler("/notfound");`